# Organize Interfaces in a semi large TD file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm working on cleaning up the definitions for the XRM respository (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/xrm) and need some guidelines for how the interfaces in definitions should be structured. (here is a cheatsheet just to get an idea of how Xrm is structure https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9-OddqJEKamWEs0MV9MMDdsWE0/view)

Basically everything is `Xrm.Page`, or `Xrm.Utility` but can go deep (`Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector`, `Xrm.Page.ui.navigation`, `Xrm.Page.data.process`, etc). I believe each of these "namespaces" should be their own interface. My question is how do you structure the interfaces in the code? Put everything at a root level?  So `Xrm.Data` (or maybe `XrmPageData`) interface is `Xrm.Page.data`? This could result in naming conflicts but makes everything simple to access. Other option is to nest them where they are found, so `Xrm.Page.Data` would exist in an `Xrm.Page` module (which is the same name, but not the `Xrm.Page` interface).

Currently the definition file is using both, I just wanted to know what the guidelines/best practices are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple truth is that users of the typing will refer to the XRM documentation for help and examples. From a usage perspective, the most obvious way is for your type definitions to resemble the API docs. Which in this case means using your second suggestion, where `Xrm.Page.data` becomes `data`, placed in a `Xrm.Page` module.